# VoiceOver on iOS not giving focus to child element after parent becomes visible

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, accessibility, voiceover

I'm developing a mobile web page on which users tap a button to toggle the display of content that's hidden by default. Here's a simple example:

```
<div role="button" id="button1">Show Link 1</div>

<div style="display:none" id="div1">
    <a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

With the tap of #button1 I'd like to display the hidden div, then place focus on Link 1.  Here's the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#button1').click(function() { 
        $('#div1').show(function() { 
            $('#link1').focus();
        })
    });
});
```

Generally this works. I've added a red border to :focus using CSS so I know the link is receiving focus after it becomes visible. However, when the link receives focus, VoiceOver on iOS doesn't announce it. VoiceOver's focus remains on the button. (I've tested this on an iPad running iOS 4.3.3 and an iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1.1).

In contrast to the the above scenario, if the element that receives focus is the same element that has just been shown, everything works fine and VoiceOver announces the newly focused link. Here's an example of a scenario that works:

```
<div role="button" id="button2">Show Link 2</div>

<div>
    <a style="display:none" href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#button2').click(function() { 
        $('#link2').show().focus();
    });
});
```

How can I get VoiceOver to announce the newly focused element when that element is a child of the element that has just become visible?

Answer (score 1):

> Generally this works.

If this means "sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work using the same code," This leads me to believe there is a timing issue. Is the link offscreen or being animated at the time it's focused? Try adding a 1 second timeout to that last callback and see if you get different results. You'll want to move focus *after* any transition animations have completed.

> Generally this works.

If this means "some code works (100% of the time) and other, similar code does not work (100% of the time)," you need to file a bug at bugreport.apple.com.

In both cases, it would also help if you posted a URL where your problem scenario could be tested.